# I have a function that's returning a char* member of a struct. I am trying to call that function and assign a string to it, but am getting an error

Tags: c, struct

Here's the function:

```
char* cycle(structtype *structname, int index){
    switch(index){
        case 1:
            return structname->structmem; //structmem is a char*
        ...}
```

Here's the calling of the function in main:

```
struct structtype *structname;
structname = malloc(sizeof(structtype));
line[250];
fgets(line,250,file);
data = strtok(line,",");
cycle(structname,index) = data;
```

Comment: ...and the error? ... and the `struct` definition? ...and `index`? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @Weather Vane The error is just "error: expression is not assignable". Index is just the index of the current member of the struct I am working with, for the example given index is only 1 as there is only 1 member in my struct. However, in my actual code there are 20.

Comment: @Justin That's because you can't assign to a function. `cycle(structname,index) = data;` this here is incorrect.

Comment: @ameyCU If it returns a char* why can I not set it equal to another char*? I'm not too familiar with C so I am relating it to a method in C# that returns a string, and then setting that method equal to another string.

Comment: You can, but the function has to `return` that from within.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is it not doing that by `return structname->structmem` where structmem is a char*?

Comment: @Justin You need `strcpy` for that. Example -  `strcpy(str,cycle(structname,index));` where `str` is `char []`. Problem is your syntax.

Comment: `cycle(structname,index) = data;` is one problem. Please see the first comment.

Comment: @ameyCU I am trying to copy `str` into the structmem though.

Comment: @Justin Inside function ? Then too you would need to return that to use in `main`.  Else the `strcpy` approach would work fine in `main`.

Comment: In C the value returned by a function is not an lvalue, but is a temporary value. You can only assign to modifiable lvalues; but you can assign the temporary value to a variable.

Comment: Are you sure you are not also getting an `lvalue required error`? Why? `cycle(structname,index)` is not an `lvalue`.

Answer (score 1):

Even the provided answer works, I think that the discussion mixes up two different problems: a) What does returning a value mean? 2. How does one assign string values?

1. Returning values

It is unnecessary to assign the return value to a variable. This is not the problem.

Let's do it from the very beginning: You have a function and this returns a value

```
int retval()
{
  return 5;
}
```

Obviously you cannot assign a value to the return value:

```
retval() = 7;
```

This is equivalent to …

```
5 = 7;
```

… which is illegal and makes completely no sense.

Okay, let's make it more complex:

```
int retval()
{
  int r = 5;
  return r;
}
```

Again, obviously you cannot assign a value to the return value:

```
retval() = 7;
```

This is *still* equivalent to …

```
5 = 7;
```

… and *not* to

```
r = 7;
```

This is because C returns values from functions by value. This is a simple, plain value. (You might call it rvalue, what can be translated with right value, meaning that it is a value on the right side of an assignment.)

Now, let's do it with your pointer:

```
int retval()
{
  char *r = malloc(…); // or whatever
  return r;
}
```

You return a pointer value (because functions return values in C), not a "pointer variable". Therefore

```
retval() = 7;
```

is *still* equivalent to …

```
0xf037ab = 7; // or whatever pointer /value/
```

… what still makes no sense and is obviously illegal. Using a variable (which is the classical example of an lvalue, but in C not the only example, see below) makes things legal, but have a different semantics:

Therefore …

```
char *mem = retval(); // legal, return value is on the right side
mem = …; // legal, because mem is a lvalue
```

… is legal, but does something different:

```
char *mem = 0xf037ab;
mem = 0x5383fa3; // or whatever pointer value
```

You simply lose the return value. (And again it is the same with `int`s.)

The difference with pointer values is, that you can use them (a rvalue) to create an lvalue, i. e.:

```
*(retval()) = 'a';
```

2. Assigning strings

In C you do not assign strings with `=`, because that would assign pointers, not the strings itself.

```
char * str = "a string";
str = "another string";
```

… does not assign the second string to `str`. Both examples simply assign a pointer to the first character of the string literal to a pointer variable.

You have to use `strcpy()` et al.

3. All together now

To put it all together, you have to use the return value as rvalue and you have to use `strcpy()` et al.

```
strcpy(data, cycle(structname,index)); // Passing an arg is possible with rvalues
```

Comment: Or, `char *tmp = cycle(structname,index); if (!tmp) {..handle error..}; strcpy (data, tmp);` I like you answer. I would only also mention "*... assign a pointer to the first character of the string **literal** to the pointer variable* `str`" (it's a nit, but might as well introduce the OP to the *string literal* terminology now...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Wow, you are a double colleague of mine. Have never seen that.